How to use FULL JOIN's in Impala? The following query runs fine in SQL Studio but not in Impala
I have a query that needs to join some tables and look for matching data between two accounts. In mysqlstudio the query runs fine but in Impala it gives me errors. I am not sure why? Do I have to use left and right to mimic a full join? The error I get is,
NotImplementedException: Error generating a valid execution plan for this query. A FULL OUTER JOIN type with no equi-join predicates can only be executed with a single node plan.
SELECT d.eid,
       d.loyaltyProgramId,
       d.playerAccountNumber,
       dcp1.PhoneNumber,
       dcp1.IsPrimary,
       dcp1.IsPreferredContactNumber,
       d.firstName,
       d.LastName,
       d.BirthDate,
       d.Gender,
       d.IsBanned,
       d.bancode,
       dc2_cust.eid,
       dc2_cust.loyaltyProgramId,
       dc2_cust.playerAccountNumber,
       dc2_cust.FirstName,
       dc2_cust.LastName,
       dc2_cust.MiddleName,
       dc2_cust.NickName,
       dc2_cust.BirthDate,
       dc2_cust.Gender,
       dc2_cust.IsBanned,
       dc2_cust.BannedReason,
       dc2_cust.BanCode,
       
       
      CONCAT(d.playeraccountnumber, '-', d.LoyaltyProgramId, ',', dc2_cust.playeraccountnumber, '-', dc2_cust.loyaltyprogramid) AS killkey


FROM gmscompliance_ref.ballybi_dcustomer d
FULL JOIN gmscompliance_ref.ballybi_dcustomerphone dcp1 ON d.customerkey = dcp1.customerkey AND d.loyaltyprogramid = dcp1.loyaltyprogramid
FULL JOIN gmscompliance_ref.ballybi_dcustomerphone dcp2_cust ON dcp1.customerkey < dcp2_cust.customerkey and (translate(dcp1.PhoneNumber, '-', ' ') = translate(dcp2_cust.PhoneNumber, '-', ' ') OR dcp1.PhoneNumber = dcp2_cust.PhoneNumber)
FULL JOIN gmscompliance_ref.ballybi_dcustomer dc2_cust ON dcp2_cust.customerkey = dc2_cust.customerkey AND dcp2_cust.loyaltyprogramid = dc2_cust.loyaltyprogramid


WHERE d.PlayerAccountStatus = 'Active'
  AND dc2_cust.PlayerAccountStatus = 'Active'
  AND d.eid <> 0
  AND d.LoyaltyProgramId <> 'GEO'
  AND left(d.FirstName,3) = left(dc2_cust.FirstName,3)
  AND d.eid <> dc2_cust.Eid
  AND d.isbanned <> dc2_cust.isbanned
  AND (d.BanCode = 'EnterpriseBan'
  OR dc2_cust.BanCode = 'EnterpriseBan')

ORDER BY d.eid;




As Impala supports FULL JOINs (https://impala.apache.org/docs/build/html/topics/impala_joins.html) please can you update your question with the actual error message(s) you are getting?

Oops, didnt realize I forgot to include that, I've edited the post and added it. Im also adding it here in case. NotImplementedException: Error generating a valid execution plan for this query. A FULL OUTER JOIN type with no equi-join predicates can only be executed with a single node plan.

Move WHERE clause conditions to ON to get true FULL JOIN result.
